# Compile with /MT instead of /MD using CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake on windows with the Windows SDK and NMake Makefiles.

By default it compiles with the `/MD` compiler switch.

How can I change it to compile with the `/MT` switch instead?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can modify the [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) variables:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```

If your CMake flags already contain `/MD`, you can ensure that the above commands are executed *after* the point at which `/MD` is inserted (the later addition of `/MT` overrides the conflicting existing option), or you can set the flags from scratch:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd")
```

Or alternatively, you could replace the existing `/MD` and `/MDd` values with `/MT` and `/MTd` respectively by doing something like:

```
set(CompilerFlags
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
        )
foreach(CompilerFlag ${CompilerFlags})
  string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${CompilerFlag} "${${CompilerFlag}}")
endforeach()
```

Comment: @Josh I've just updated the answer.  If it's still not exactly what you're after, show the relevant bit of your CMakeLists.txt and I'm sure there'll be a neat answer.

Comment: @Josh I made a minor mistake in the `string(REPLACE...)` command - it's fixed now.

Comment: This request is very common - its strange that CMake still doesnt have a macro or setting to support this out of the box. I end up doing this in almost every project - especially ones that have external dependencies like GoogleMock that have their own default opinions about compiler ABI

Comment: @kert - It's more than strange, it's mystifying.

Comment: Can anyone tell me in which file in vcpkg this change should be made?

Comment: Is there any new official solution for this problem?

Comment: When changing /MD or /MT, be sure to delete all prior CMake output. If binary directory has CMake files from a previous attempt, I found that CMake would appear to have the proper switch through [MESSAGE()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298278/cmake-print-out-all-accessible-variables-in-a-script) inspection, but build command line continued to use the prior stale switch setting.

Comment: @xuhdev please refer to my answer. You should use `set(... CACHE ... FORCE)`

Comment: @Fraser can this option be set from the command line using by running `cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MT" ..`?

Comment: @cyrusbehr Good question. I think the answer is no. How did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I realize this is a nearly 10 year old answer so I should have known better, however BE WARNED: if you do `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd")` (or `MT`) on newer versions of CMake, you overwrite some other flags set by the platform module scripts (e.g., `/Zi`). This was entirely my fault, but I was unable to debug in vscode when using this. I couldn't figure out for the life of me why debugging stopped breaking on my breakpoints -- the issue was this setting stepping on the compiler flags. I **highly** recommend using the `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` answer instead.

Answer (score 110):

CMake finally added proper support for this in version 3.15 with the [`MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html#prop_tgt:MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY) target property:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)
project(my_project)

add_executable(foo foo.c)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
             MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
```

You can also specify a global default by setting the [`CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html#variable:CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY) variable instead.

Comment: It works somehow w/o the `cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)` on 3.16.3, is it really required?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan As usual with policies, if your `cmake_minimum_required` is new enough, you don't need to request the new behavior explicitly. I mostly included the policy in the answer so that people are aware that a policy exists for this feature and look it up if they care about the compatibility implications.

Comment: this should be the accepted solution, at least for modern cmake. this is far less opaque than hacking CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS...

Comment: @DavidKarla Except for the fact that this answer was given six years after the original question was asked, not to say that the person who's asked it hasn't logged in since 2015.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: And make sure you cleared your build folder before cmake sync, or you will get a `D9025` warning.

Answer (score 21):

It seems that for *Visual Studio 15 2017* and *CMake 3.12* the way to replace `/MD` by `/MT` is by adding this snippet to the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(
        $<$<CONFIG:>:/MT> #---------|
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd> #---|-- Statically link the runtime libraries
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/MT> #--|
    )
endif()
```

I found this solution in the official CMake repository: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18390

**Edit**: As commented by [@bernardo-ramos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4626775/bernardo-ramos), this block should be added before the `add_executable` or `add_library`.

Comment: Note: this block should be added before the `add_executable` or `add_library`

Answer (score 4):

I have to use `set( ... CACHE ... FORCE)` to overwrite MSVC's default cache.

If I do not use this method, MSVC still outputs `/MD` options.

```
set(CompilerFlags
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
        CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
        )
foreach(CompilerFlag ${CompilerFlags})
    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${CompilerFlag} "${${CompilerFlag}}")
    set(${CompilerFlag} "${${CompilerFlag}}" CACHE STRING "msvc compiler flags" FORCE)
    message("MSVC flags: ${CompilerFlag}:${${CompilerFlag}}")
endforeach()
```

Comment: After hours of wasted time, this was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Though this still seems to link some of the standard libraries dynamically: MSVCP140.dll, VCRUNTIME140_1.dll, VCRUNTIME140.dll, api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll ...

Comment: @Miscreant the only thing I can suggest is that to check all generated command line arguments in cmake's cache. The cmake's rules are complicated, while the MSVC's system is messy.

Answer (score 4):

Since CMake 3.15 `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` property does that
See documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

Here is example to set target property accordingly

```
set_target_properties(${this_target} PROPERTIES
        CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DebugDLL>
        )
```

This snippet is compatible with multi-config generators (MSbuild, Ninja Multi-Config, Xcode).

It sets non-Debug configuration to use static multi-threaded runtimes and MultiThreadedDebugDLL for Debug configuration.

MultiThreadedDebugDLL builds faster, for more interactive development experience during debugging.

Here is an example https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/44f0dd7cb619c6f33565e9d07250bfc6581bd32a/cmake/bins.cmake#L123

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ucm_set_runtime](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_set_runtime) - this macro will replace the flags for static or dynamic runtime - to see the effects, use [ucm_print_flags](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_print_flags) (also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113017/setting-the-msvc-runtime-in-cmake) Stack Overflow question).