# MSVC Incremental linking with CMake and the Ninja generator

Tags: cmake, ninja, incremental-linking

I build a shared library with CMake and the Ninja generator on Windows. I'd like to use incremental linking to reduce the time required for linking.

I tried to set `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` to `"/incremental"` but this flag is always overridden by a `"/INCREMENTAL:NO"` which is appended by CMake.

I also tried to set `MSVC_INCREMENTAL_DEFAULT` to `ON`, but this didn't have any effect.

So how can I get incremental linking working with CMake and the Ninja generator?

Comment: In my VS toolchain file I have `SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/INCREMENTAL:YES" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)`. So I assume `SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "/INCREMENTAL:YES" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)` should also work, but would overwrite all of CMake's defaults.

Comment: I figured it out. Since I set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Release`, I had to set `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` with `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/incremental")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

I use a similar `SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/INCREMENTAL:YES" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)` in my VS toolchain file.

Be aware that CMake does combine/append its linker flags out of the general e.g. `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` and the build type specific parts like `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE`.

So you have to either find out where CMake does set `/INCREMENTAL:NO` for shared libraries - as you and I have done - and overwrite it with:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/INCREMENTAL:YES")
```

Or you could iterate over the different build configuration specific variables like:

- [CMake compile with /MT instead of /MD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172856/cmake-compile-with-mt-instead-of-md)
- [CMake: How to set a preprocessor define for all build configurations except one ?](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-a-preprocessor-define-for-all-build-configurations-except-one-td6450520.html)