# How to change Visual Studio CMake run-time library

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am currently trying to compile some code with Visual Studio 2017 `Version 15.7.0` and am having issues changing the run-time library. I know there are similar questions where you would normally right click on the project and then change it through the user interface that appears; however, since I am using CMake this does not work as that user interface does not appear.

The current default for Visual Studios is set to use `/MD` run-time library and I want to use `/MT`. I have tried setting this variable in the top level `CMakeLists.txt`, but it appears to get overwritten. The only way I have found that I can build my project successfully is to change all instances of `/MD` in the `CMakeCache.txt`. While this is a temporary hack I was wondering what is the proper set this variable so that Visual Studio uses `/MT` when compiling.

I have tried this previous answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172856/cmake-compile-with-mt-instead-of-md), but I am not getting it to work. Here is my current top level `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.11)

project ("WindowCMakeProject")
message(STATUS "Using CMake Version " ${CMAKE_VERSION})

#This project heavily uses C++ 17
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#Setup Boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)

if ( WIN32 )
    add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME     ON)
    #Solution from prior answer doesn't work
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd")
endif()


find_package(Boost 1.66.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

#Setup OpenSSL
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

#Setup Google Protobuf
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

if ( DEBUG_PRINT )
    set(DEBUG_PRINT_MODE 1)
else()
    set(DEBUG_PRINT_MODE 0)
endif()

#Add Util Headers
add_subdirectory(Utils)
set (UTILS_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Utils/include)

#Setup Server Library
set (SERVER_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ServerLibrary/include)
add_subdirectory (ServerLibrary)
include_directories(${SERVER_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#Setup Message Helper Library
set (MESSAGE_HELPER_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MessageHelperLibrary/include)
add_subdirectory(MessageHelperLibrary)
include_directories(${MESSAGE_HELPER_INCLUDE_DIR})

#Setup Protobufs(These are built by CMake)
add_subdirectory(ProtoFiles)
set (PROTOBUF_MESSAGE_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ProtoFiles)


add_subdirectory (ExchangeHandlerServer)
add_subdirectory (TestServer)
add_subdirectory (TestClient)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way but this is how I fixed it,

```
if ( MSVC )
    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}_INIT")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE})

    string(REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO})
endif ( MSVC )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question can be first in google search I'll add one more answer 3 years later

In CMake 3.15 there's new property MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY that allows you to choose runtime library. Since that version, by default, you can no longer set runtime library via `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

So for CMake and higher 3.15 correct code would be

```
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY 
    MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (MSVC)
Message ( STATUS "Setting MSVC switches")
string(REPLACE "/MTd" "/MDd" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
string(REPLACE "/MT" "/MD" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}_INIT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
Endif (MSVC)
```