# Compiling OpenCV without Visual C++ runtime dependency

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile the OpenCV 4.6.0 using cMake 3.23 and Visual studio 2022 and I need to make sure that it will not depend on VC++ runtime DLLs.
The problem is no matter what I do, the ***opencv_world460.dll*** will end up dependent on `VCRUNTIME140.DLL` and `VCRUNTIME140_1.DLL`.
Please note that I'm using Visual Studio 2022 which has the version number **17**, but the compiled dll is dependent on version **14** runtimes. Why?
I have also unchecked the `BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT` and the result is still the same.
So how can I make sure my DLL is not dependent on any `VCRUNTIMExxx.DLL`?

Comment: The numbers are just confusing. Version 17 is for the IDE, Visual Studio. The "platform toolkit" is still at version 14.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a full statically linked application. I am not sure MSVC will even allow this any more. The fact is the compiler is going to always use the libraries provided in the runtime. You are just trying to bundle it with your application code instead of having to install it separately or expect it to be present on target systems. I assume?

Comment: @MikelF MSVC allows it by setting **Runtime Library** in **Properties >> Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> Code Generation** to **/MT** for Release and **/MTd** for debug. But I want to force this setting from the CMake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile with /MT instead of /MD using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172856/compile-with-mt-instead-of-md-using-cmake)

Comment: @MikelF Had already tried it, did not work.

Comment: ***Please note that I'm using Visual Studio 2022 which has the version number 17, but the compiled dll is dependent on version 14 runtimes. Why?*** All versions of VS from 2015 through 2022 share the same redistributable and have binary compatibility: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170)

Comment: ***Had already tried it, did not work*** When you edited the CMakeLists.txt for opencv did you try this option for each target and VS Configuration: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70420052/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70420052/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm at line 142 of CMakeLists.txt we have `project(OpenCV CXX C)` followed by `if(MSVC)` at line 144. I added `add_compile_options` inside that if statement. Not sure what you mean by "**each target and VS Configuration**".

Comment: The answer I linked said to `set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
  MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")` that sets the runtime for the Debug only in the TARGET `foo` each add_executable() add_library() is a target you need to set for each target and each configuration Debug, Release ... The documentation for this is here: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html)

Comment: @drescherjm CMakeLists.txt for OpenCV 4.6 does not have any `add_executable()` or `add_library()` in it.

Comment: It has to somewhere it could use a CMake macro or function for that. Edit: It looks like the build system is pretty complex.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found was to uncheck the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` and `BUILD_opencv_world` and created **static .lib** files which I then linked those libs into my app.
keep in mind using this method because you don't create the world package, you will have to link many libs like below. All of these files will be in `\opencv-4.6.0\Build\install\x64\vc17\staticlib` folder.

```
#if defined(_DEBUG)
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_features2d460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_calib3d460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_objdetect460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgcodecs460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_flann460d")
#pragma comment(lib, "aded")
#pragma comment(lib, "IlmImfd")
#pragma comment(lib, "ippiwd")
#pragma comment(lib, "ittnotifyd")
#pragma comment(lib, "libjpeg-turbod")
#pragma comment(lib, "libopenjp2d")
#pragma comment(lib, "libpngd")
#pragma comment(lib, "libprotobufd")
#pragma comment(lib, "libtiffd")
#pragma comment(lib, "libwebpd")
#pragma comment(lib, "quircd")
#pragma comment(lib, "zlibd")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_features2d460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_calib3d460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_objdetect460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgcodecs460")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_flann460")
#pragma comment(lib, "ade")
#pragma comment(lib, "IlmImf")
#pragma comment(lib, "ippiw")
#pragma comment(lib, "ittnotify")
#pragma comment(lib, "libjpeg-turbo")
#pragma comment(lib, "libopenjp2")
#pragma comment(lib, "libpng")
#pragma comment(lib, "libprotobuf")
#pragma comment(lib, "libtiff")
#pragma comment(lib, "libwebp")
#pragma comment(lib, "quirc")
#pragma comment(lib, "zlib")
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "ippicvmt")
```