# Static linking .lib files in cmake

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I am trying to use IUP to create a gui program in Windows 10. I am also using Clion+MSVC as an IDE. IUP has both .lib and .dll files for download and all goes well when I don't specify how to link in cmake; cmake automatically tries to link dynamically with iup.dll when there are no custom flags about linking.

However, when I try to statically link iup.dll with a compiler flag `/MT`, the compiler automatically changes `/MT` to `/MD` and just link dynamically.

Here's the cmake code I used to force compiler static linking:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /MT")
```

and then I get this warning:

```
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MT' with '/MD'
```

Any way to "force" cmake and compiler to statically link library to my program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113017/setting-the-msvc-runtime-in-cmake

Answer (score 2):

Another options:

```
set_target_properties(TARGET_LIB PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_OPTIONS "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/MT>"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Cmake had commands to automatically set almost all these flags.

Try adding `add_library(iup.dll STATIC IMPORTED)` before the `target_link_libraries`

[Cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_library.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default CMake uses the MSVC dynamic runtime library (`/MD`) when building static or shared libraries.

You need to replace the `/MD` setting in the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`/`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variables with `/MT`.
This can be done by the follwoing commands:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

For a complete solution please see the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113017/setting-the-msvc-runtime-in-cmake)